# Typescript: How to be typesafe on exempting an enum value in new interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently working on creating a new method that wants to do an exemption of a specific enum value.

```
import { Overwrite } from 'utility-types';

enum Gender {
  boy = 'boy',
  girl = 'girl',
}

type Human = {
  gender: Gender,
  age: number,
}

type BoyGender = Exclude<Gender, 'girl'>;

type HumanBoy = Overwrite<
  Human,
  {
    gender: BoyGender;
  }
>;

export function accept(human: HumanBoy): void {
  console.log(human)
}

accept({
  gender: Gender.boy, // type error here
  age: 2
})
```

When I use the enum of `Gender` again, I get a type error saying that

`Types of property 'gender' are incompatible. Type 'Gender' is not assignable to type 'BoyGender'`

Currently not sure why this is happening since `BoyGender` gets its value from `Gender` enum with the exemption of girl. Is there a way to pass this type error rather than creating a new enum with only boy?

Comment: Your code runs in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQG4FMoHcrBuuAXzgDMoIQ4ByAVxmABs8BPAWhmbHQGcqBuAFAD0AOxqUA4qIAmmRALhwARhGZwAvNRXMqAGgVwA5sCgMN1Y6b0DCQjlzgAJcQEMR5hAcMzMALjhSIrJQ+oou3v5iIEqY+rYC9gQAQqqBweYAogAeAMYMNLIAPGmxFiYMVAB8ggmcBM4gbilqmmiYOHjohQYNbqHyioreQX5wzSVQgoq21ULoWZCwpDQiOfQQ7i45OehgMAAUABauIv69Is0AlP6oEMDSA3A5G9wQDOgAdAwQhkcnlzYhFsdnt9p4hj4oP4Jh9tLo4AB6BFwRJwTDkKBwQ6YdAGcLofwAJhsAKAA) just fine (TS 4.5.4).

Comment: hmm. strange. I am at TS 4.2.2. I am not getting the error on the TS playground but I am getting error in my tests in jest.